# Solving $|\frac{x+1}{x-2}|<1$ and $\frac{6w+7}{2w-1}- \frac{6w+1}{2w}=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, real-numbers

I want to find
the real number such that $|\frac{x+1}{x-2}|<1$ and find the values $w$ such that :

$$\frac{6w+7}{2w-1}- \frac{6w+1}{2w}=1$$.

By playing a little bit with this first inequality I have found out that the real numbers $(-\infty,0]$ satisfy the inequality. But when Im trying to prove this I got te following:

$|\frac{x+1}{x-2}|<1$ means that $-1< \frac{x+1}{x-2}<1$ from the left inequality I got $-x+2<x+1$. Then I got $\frac{1}{2}<x$. From the right inequality I got that $x+1 < x-2$, but this gives me no information for $x$ since its cancelled. So what can I conclude from the right inequality? Does all the real numbers satisfy this inequality are $x \in (- \infty,  \frac{1}{2})$?

For the second equality I got that:

$$\frac{6w+7}{2w-1}- \frac{6w+1}{2w}= \frac{6w+7-6w-1}{(2w+1)(2w)}=\frac{6}{4w^{2}+2w}$$

Then I got $0=4w^{2}+2(w)-6$ which can be solved by the quadratic formula but this gives me values $\frac{-6}{4}$ and $1$. But clearly when $w=1$ the equality doesnt hold.

But Im stuck there. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like elementary algebra.  For the frst $x\lt 1/2$ works while for the second, your algebra needs fixing.

Comment: I know, seems also like the second equality doesnt hold. I edited my question @herbsteinberg

Comment: Do the algebra correctly first. Then solve for $w$.  The combined fraction is wrong, even the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle the inequality here is by squaring the absolute value symbol away:

$$\begin{align}
\left|x+1\over x-2\right|\lt1
&\iff\left(x+1\over x-2\right)^2\lt1\\
&\iff(x+1)^2\lt(x-2)^2\\
&\iff x^2+2x+1\lt x^2-4x+4\\
&\iff6x\lt3\\
&\iff x\lt1/2
\end{align}$$

so the inequality is satisfied for all $x\in(-\infty,1/2)$.

The one subtlety here is that we need to check that $x=2$, where the original left hand side is undefined, is not in the interval $(-\infty,1/2)$. If, for example, the inequality sign had pointed the other way, the final answer would be $(1/2,2)\cup(2,+\infty)$ instead of $(1/2,+\infty)$.

For the equation in $w$, you made two errors in the first step. It should be

$${6w+7\over2w-1}-{6w+1\over2w}={(6w+7)(2w)-(6w+1)(2w-1)\over(2w-1)(2w)}$$

That is, you forgot to cross multiply in the numerator, and you changed $2w-1$ to $2w+1$ in the denominator.  Can you take things from there?

Comment: @Barry_Cipra Thanks! I just developed your last inequality and I got $\frac{-10w-1}{(2w-1)(2w)}$. Still dont know how this is equal to $1$? :/

Comment: @Sok, you can set it equal to $1$ and then solve for $w$, as you did with your incorrect expression. But doublecheck your numerator first. I get something quite different from $-10w-1$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the first one is $(-\infty, \frac 1 2 )$. Remember that if you multiply an inequality by a negative number the inequality sign changes. Consider the cases $x>2$ and $x <2$ separately. When $x >2$ it is easy to see that there is no solution. When $x<2$ we get $2-x>x+1>x-2$ which reduces to $x<\frac 1  2$.
The second part is obviously false. Take $w=1$ to get a  contradiction. Perhaps you are asked to find all $w$ for which the equation holds. This can be done by solving a quadratic equaion in $w$.

Comment: $x\geq1/2$ doesn't satisfy the inequality.

Comment: @innerproduct Thanks for pointing out.